# Cast unsigned long to int in VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, types, casting

I need to pass a 'unsigned long' type argument to a function which only takes int.
I did not find a safe way to cast it on MSDN. Could someone please share a safe function to do this?

Comment: you can't conclusively make it safe; an unsigned long can hold a larger number than an int can.  As long as your values never exceed MAXINT, then you can just cast it.

Comment: How do you define *safe*? What do you want the result to be when the value contained in the `unsigned long` exceeds that that can fit into an `int`?

Comment: @Joe: It's `INT_MAX`, not `MAXINT`.

Comment: Wow, right. MAXINT is a Pascal thing, I think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "safe" way to convert an `unsigned long` value to `int`, since an `unsigned long` can hold values that cannot be represented in an `int`.

You could do something like this:

```
unsigned long arg = some_value;
if (arg <= INT_MAX) {
    func(arg); // the value will be implicitly converted
}
else {
    // do something else
}
```

Note that it's not necessary *in this case* to check against `INT_MIN`. If the argument were `long` rather than `unsigned long`, you'd want to check against the lower and upper bounds:

```
if (arg >= INT_MIN && arg <= INT_MAX) ...
```

Of course you'll have to decide what to do if the value doesn't fit.

Answer (score 1):

There is no safe way since `unsigned long` contains values that cannot be represented in `int`.

But if you are sure that the conversion is safe, you can write `(int)argument` or `static_cast<int>(argument)` or simply pass an argument as is, the language will perform the conversion automatically.